# How to parse a JSON with an unknown schema in rapture-json?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, rapture.io

I'm using Rapture JSON to parse a JSON message this way

```
 for {
    id <- parsedJson.inputEvent.fields.id.as[String]
    inputFields <- parsedJson.fieldSet.fields.as[Map[String, Any]]
    additionalFields <- extractAdditionalFields(parsedJson)
  } yield (
    (id, inputFields),
     additionalFields)
```

The problem is that `inputFields` is parsed always as a Map[String,String]] and I can't seem to make it parse as a Double/Integer correctly. I'm rather sure it used to work correctly but right now it does not. The JSON is valid, well formed and other parsers parse the values as numbers and not string. Is there an elegant way to enforce the correct parsing?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of the jawt backend. Moving to lift solved the problem.